# Simplified maximum value conditional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Lets say you have a conditional where you're finding a number, and returning that number, but only up to a certain number:

```
var scale = 15 + Math.floor(count / 100) * 5 > 20 ? 20 : 15 + Math.floor(count / 100) * 5;
```

So this will return the calculated value up to 20; anything over 20 is just "20".

Is there any sort of shorthand to return a max value? Here I'm calculating it twice, which seems wasteful. I know I could define a var separately for the inner equation and use it twice, but I wonder if there's a more elegant solution I am unaware of?

Comment: That code generates two different numbers.... :) Why are you not just generating a random number in a range to start???

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```js
const scale = Math.min(20, 15 + Math.floor(count / 100) * 5)
```

In case you need to do the opposite (limit to a minimum), you can use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).